# Cannot find namespace 'Webpack' during Aurelia application build with Webpack

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack, aurelia

I am trying to set up an Aurelia application with Webpack, but I get the error all the time:

```
[at-loader] Checking finished with 1 errors
[at-loader] ./node_modules/aurelia-loader-webpack/dist/commonjs/aurelia-loader-webpack.d.ts:31:51
    TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'Webpack'.
```

I installed @types/webpack and also modules: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-dev-middleware and webpack-hot-middleware. I tried everything I could find, but nothing works, I am stuck.

This is my tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceRoot": "src",
    "allowJs": true,
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "lib": [
      "es2017", "dom"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist",
    "static"
  ],
  "typeAcquisition": {
    "include": [
      "src"
    ]
  }
}
```

I saw that people have similar problems with modules and namespaces, but not a single answer was working for me. Anyone has an idea what might be the problem?

Comment: what does your package.json look like?

Comment: Did you figure it out? I got the same problem, compared the project with skeleton and did not find anyting. I got errors in: ./node_modules/aurelia-webpack-plugin/dist/types/AureliaDependenciesPlugin.d.ts and 27 others files. But it compiles successfully

Comment: Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: I was using `aurelia-webpack-plugin@2.0.0-rc.3` but rolled back to `aurelia-webpack-plugin@2.0.0-rc.2` and I stopped receiving these errors.

Answer (score 1):

As we could not tackle the problem nicely and because this error was preventing us from creating successful builds, we ended up by simple deleting the relevant declaration file (*node_modules/aurelia-loader-webpack/dist/commonjs/aurelia-loader-webpack.d.ts*).

I know this is not the preferred solution, however it works and it shouldn't be of any problem, as the *node_modules* directory should anyway be ignored by the awesome-typescript-loader. Some how it wasn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare to a Webpack/Aurelia setup that works.

Here is a sequence of windows console commands that easily create such a skeleton.  Note it works with .NET though, which may not match your needs. But it should be possible to simplify the resulting skeleton to work without the .Net parts.

Steps:

```
dotnet new --install Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaTemplates::*
mkdir [Your Project Folder]
cd [Your Project Folder]
dotnet new aurelia
dotnet restore
npm install
```

Set an environment variable to tell ASP.NET to run in development mode:

- If you’re using PowerShell in Windows, execute
  `$Env:ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = "Development"`
- If you’re using cmd.exe in Windows, execute `setx
  ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT "Development"`, and then restart your command
  prompt to make the change take effect
- If you’re using Mac/Linux, execute `export ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development`

Finally:

```
dotnet run
```